# Associate Amazon EC2 instance with my own domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I tried to deploy a node project into an Amazon EC2 instance and associate it with my own custom domain yesterday.

The application works fine by using public DNS that is offered by EC2. I updated the nameserver of my domain, added domain name and public IP address into Route 53. I tried `dig invia.ca` command in the terminal, but nothing changed.

[image: domain nameserver]

[image: route 53 setting]
    $ dig in-via.ca

```
Domain name: in-via.ca
Domain status: registered
Creation date: 2017/03/27
Expiry date: 2018/03/27
Updated date: 2017/04/28
DNSSEC: Unsigned

Registrar:
Name: Web Hosting Canada (7081936 Canada Inc.)
Number: 5000080

Name servers:
ns-1350.awsdns-40.org
ns-1824.awsdns-36.co.uk
ns-744.awsdns-29.net
ns-315.awsdns-39.com

% WHOIS look-up made at 2017-04-29 03:36:40 (GMT)
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106716/domain-not-resolving-after-transferring-to-aws/43106880#43106880 - it's not always obvious how to use Route 53.

Comment: @Allen -- I've added the current `dig` output. Is that what you're getting? What do you want to be different?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it suppose to display the four nameserver address I entered above under authority section and additional section? and u missed '-' between 'in' and 'via' too..

Comment: `in-via.ca` is now resolving to `35.163.97.40` so the DNS looks okay now.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes it's working now thx indeed. i changed nothing. My previous setting is correct. I cannot believe it really takes around 24 hours to get nameserver updated. jesus crist! But currently I have to add ':8080' behind the www.in-via.ca in order to view the website. Do u know how can i get rid of it?

Comment: Configure your web server to run on port 80 instead of 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dig NS in-via.ca`. You need to update the name servers at your registrar (Web Hosting Canada, according to WHOIS). You can see that AWS has the correct info with `dig @ns-315.awsdns-39.com in-via.ca`.

Comment: I  tried the command above. for somehow the nameserver does not change after I updated it. it's weird. I am pretty sure I changed nameserver and clicked changenameserver button in my WHC accounts. Why is everyone says i need to update the nameservers in Go Dadddy.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Seems we both made the same mistake there. I updated my answer. It looks like `dig in-via.ca` now matches `dig @ns-315.awsdns-39.com in-via.ca` so you should be good.

Comment: what's the difference between dig in-via.ca and dig @ns-315.awsdns-39.com in-via.ca. but  the web page still only shows whole bunch of information about Web Hosting Canada after i entered the www.in-via.ca in the address field.

Comment: The `@ns-315.awsdns-39.com` tells dig to query that DNS server. Without it, it will use the one your system is configured to use. The site is not responding for me; you have some other problem, possibly the firewall.

Comment: it's working now thx indeed. i changed nothing. My previous setting is correct. I cannot believe it really takes around 24 hours to get nameserver updated. jesus crist! But currently I have to add ':8080' behind the www.in-via.ca in order to view the website. Do u know how can i get rid of it?

Comment: Yes, it can take a while for changes to propagate through the Internet, due to TTLs. When you visit a web page in your browser, port 80 (for http) or 443 (for https) is used by default. The server you're using is configured to listen on a different port (8080). You need to change its configuration to listen on port 80/443. I have no idea what it is, so I can't comment on how to do that. You should ask a new question for that.